# Passing byte array through serialport

Tags: c#, serial-port

I want to pass the following byte array through serial port.

```
array[j].abc = 2;
array[j].def = 4;
array[j].gh = 6;
array[j].ij = 0;
array[j].jl = 1;
array[j].fg= 1;
array[j].bh = 2;
```

I passed the byte array as follow

```
byte[] wtbin = TestSerializer.StructureToByteArray(array[j]);
byte[] bharr = new byte[1];
bharr[0] = wtbin[i];

serialPort1.Write(bharr, 0, 1);
```

But serialport  receives it as letters like B,B etc. How can 
I receive it as numbers??

Comment: What do you mean with "*the serialport receives*"? The serial port doesn't handle data.

Comment: @CommuSoft:  I used 'PUTTY.Exe' to see the data.. Here i meant that values shows in putty is like B  etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a whole byte array (generally named buffer) into the `serialPort.Write()` method. What you are doing instead is passing a single byte to the method. In your case the call to the method would be something like:

```
serialport1.Write(wtbin, 0, wtbin.Length);
```

You can read more about SerialPort on [MSDN - SerialPort Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Additionally keep in mind that you are sending bytes, not ASCII text. Depending on what you are sending PUTTY may display different things. In order to convert a byte array(buffer) back to ASCII, you can use

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
```

Hope this helps :)